# Openshift/Kubernetes container memory continuously increasing while heap memory allocation and usage is consistent without any load

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift

I have a java application deployed in Openshift. I have define 2GB and 3GB as min and max heap size. Also have define 4GB as limit and request (Guarantee Qos) in deployment config for pod.

What I observed is Openshift/Kubernetes container memory continuously increasing without any load while heap memory allocation and usage is consistent

rss ->  3143958528 - 3077279744 =~ 66 MB

```
sh-4.2$ ps -aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
1011420+    28  9.6  3.0 13459992 3020416 ?    Sl   May17  91:21 java -Xmx3072m -Xms2048m -Dja

sh-4.2$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat
cache 122351616
rss 3077279744
rss_huge 2881486848
mapped_file 19517440
swap 0
```

```
sh-4.2$ ps -aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
1011420+    28  9.5  3.1 13463076 3085024 ?    Sl   May17 106:12 java -Xmx3072m -Xms2048m -Dja

sh-4.2$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat
cache 122466304
rss 3143958528
rss_huge 2936012800
mapped_file 19595264
swap 0
```

There is a significant increase in pod memory utilization with 10 to 12 hr.
Currently it is around rss - 3143958528 Byte , same is visible in below graph
Also heap allocation/utilization is consistent

[image]

[image]

I am not able to understand why container memory is continuously increasing ?